# Confusion with operator '!' in c

Tags: c, operators, cs50

I've seen the operator `!` being used in multiple places differently and I still don't get how it actually works. My basic understanding is it reverses the value from true to false and vice versa. If it reversed to true the statement triggers. Let's take an example.

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    if (!(a == 6))
    {
        printf("unlike\n");
    }
    if (!(a == 5))
    {
        printf("like\n");
    }
}
```

In the code above since `a` is `5` it ends up printing "unlike" because the false statement that `a` is `6` got reversed. Now let's take another example.

```
int main(void)
{
    string i = "abc";
    string j = "cab";
    string k = "abc";
    if (!strcmp(i, j))
    {
        printf("unlike\n");
    }
    if (!strcmp(i, k))
    {
        printf("like\n");
    }
}
```

The `string` type has been taken from the `cs50.h` header and `strcmp` from `string.h`. strcmp returns value 0 if the two strings are alike and if unlike depending on the alphabetical order returns a positive or negative value. Now if we follow the logic in the previous example, since i and j are unlike, and false it should be reversed to true and unlike should be the output. But I tried running the code and the result was like.

I am confused. Can anyone please explain this to me clearly? Feel free to use other examples too. I could always get away with not using `!` but I just want to learn what it is and how to properly use it.

Comment: `strcmp(i, j)` returns a negative value, and applying `!` to it yields `0`.  `strcmp(i, k)` returns `0`, and `!0` is `1`.  So it prints `like`.

Comment: @TomKarzes but isn't 0 supposed to be a true value?

Comment: No, in fact `0` is a *canonical* false value.  Non-zero values are true, and zero values are false.  Try it.  Do `if (0)` and `if (1)` and see what happens.

Comment: Huh, I got confused because of the return 0 which is used to say the program worked.

Comment: Don't use `!` with `strcmp()` — even though lots of people do it.  Use `if (strcmp(i, j) == 0)` to test for equality; use `if (strcmp(i, j) != 0)` to test for inequality; use `if (strcmp(i, j) > 0)` to test for `i` comes after `j`; use `if (strcmp(i, j) >= 0)` to test for `i` is equal to or comes after `j`; use `if (strcmp(i, j) < 0)` to test for `i` comes before `j`; use `if (strcmp(i, j) <= 0)` to test for `i` is equal to or comes before `j`.  This is much easier to understand, IMNSHO.

Comment: @AneeshKandrakota `return 0` in `main` is used to indicate "no errors occurred during execution" while any other value indicates unsuccessful execution.  This has two advantages: you can return different values for different error conditions, and there is only one value (0) to test when you need to know whether a program finished executing successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A boolean in C is an integer with zero for false and non-zero for true.

`strcmp` returns 0 when the compared strings are identical and a non-zero value depending on the difference otherwise. Therefore, `strcmp(i,k)` is seen as "false". The `!` then changes this to "true", which leads to your current output.

Comment: More accurately, a _boolean expression_ can be seen as zero or non-zero. Since C actually has a `_Bool` type, which can only hold the values 0 or 1 (`false` or `true`). Assigning a non-zero value to such a type will yield `1`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case `a = 5`. then `if (!(a == 6))`; here `a = 6` is not true (false), so it's something like this. `if (!(false))` it means `if (true)`. That's why it prints "unlike".

`strcmp(i, j)` returns 0 if the strings i and j match; otherwise, it will return a non-zero value. In your case,

```
(!strcmp(i, j))
```

Here `i` and `j` are not equal so `strcmp` will return a non-zero value because `i != j`. So `!(1)` means `not(1)` means `0`, so the `if` condition is false because of zero. Therefore it'll not execute the `printf("unlike\n")` line.

```
(!strcmp(i, k))
```

Here `i` and `k` are same so `strcmp` will return `0`. `!(0)` means `not(0) = 1`  so the `if` condition is true. It will execute the `printf("like\n")` line.